# Jquery and ASP.NET ajax call to .NET is giving 500 error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I created an object like so:

`Object {ABC-123: "XYZ", ABC-112: "LAX"}`

and I am trying to send that object to .NET, but I am getting a 500 error, here is how I am sending this object:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/vendorProject/api/connection/updateVendorItem",
            data: JSON.stringify(editObject),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
```

the variable editObject is the object above. I don't think this part is the problem.

I am sending it to this controller in ASP.NET:

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendorItem(string[] edittedItems)
        {
            ConnectionClass jobs = new ConnectionClass();
            return jobs.updateVendors(edittedItems);
        }
```

and then sending it this class:

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendors(string[] items)
        {
            VendorUpdateCell = new List<VendorUpdateClass>();

            VendorUpdateClass vendorUpdatedItem = new VendorUpdateClass();

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++ ){
                vendorUpdatedItem.job = items[i];
                vendorUpdatedItem.task = items[i];
                vendorUpdatedItem.vendor = items[i];

                VendorUpdateCell.Add(vendorUpdatedItem);
            }

            return VendorUpdateCell;
        }
```

Now here is something interesting when I remove the loop from my class so it looks like so:

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendors(string[] items)
        {
            VendorUpdateCell = new List<VendorUpdateClass>();

            VendorUpdateClass vendorUpdatedItem = new VendorUpdateClass();

            //for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++ ){
                vendorUpdatedItem.job = "aaa";
                vendorUpdatedItem.task = "bbb";
                vendorUpdatedItem.vendor = "ccc";

                VendorUpdateCell.Add(vendorUpdatedItem);
            //}

            return VendorUpdateCell;
        }
```

this does not give me a 500 error, in fact I get the success alert from the ajax call. So I am assuming I am doing something wrong to loop through my object in .NET Does anyone have any suggestions ?

What I am expecting is `vendorUpdatedItem.job` equals ABC-123, `vendorUpdatedItem.task` equals ABC-123 and `vendorUpdatedItem.vendor` equals XYZ (for the first item anyways)

There is another problem...I can't debug my .NET code as my IIS is not working.

but here is the response I get from my network calls:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at VendorProject.Models.ConnectionClass.updateVendors(String[] items)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

Comment: Add the following code in your failure section and try to find out the exact error message: .failure(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //what is returned in errorThrown?
    });

Comment: While I wouldn't necessarily expect it to cause an *error*, your initial loop code is updating the same object and placing a reference to that same, single object in each array element. In that structure, you really need a "new" VendorUpdateClass for each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Javascript object should look something like this:

```
var vendorUpdatLists= [ { job: "ABC-123", task: "XYZ" },  { job: "ABC-333", task: "LAX" }];
```

And your method definition should look like:

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendors(List<VendorUpdateClass> vendorUpdateItems) {
  // It's time to use the list!
  if (vendorUpdateItems != null && vendorUpdateItems.Count() > 0) {
    string job = vendorUpdateItems[0].job; // ABC-123
    string task = vendorUpdateItems[0].task; // XYZ
  }
}
```

Lastly, I recommend that you follow the proper naming conventions. For example, a public property should start with a capital letter.

```
string job = vendorUpdateItem.Job;
```

Comment: okay I tried it out, now I get errors in my loop `for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++ ){
                vendorUpdatedItem.job = items[i];
                vendorUpdatedItem.task = items[i];
                vendorUpdatedItem.vendor = items[i];

                VendorUpdateCell.Add(vendorUpdatedItem);
            }`

Comment: `Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.List<VendorProject.Models.VendorUpdateClass>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<VendorProject.Models.VendorUpdateClass>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and `Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'VendorProject.Models.VendorUpdateClass' to 'string' `

Comment: I changed my loop to so: `foreach (object objectItems in items)
            {
                VendorUpdateClass vendorUpdatedItem = new VendorUpdateClass();
                vendorUpdatedItem.job = objectItems.job;
                vendorUpdatedItem.task = "bbb";
                vendorUpdatedItem.vendor = "ccc";

                VendorUpdateCell.Add(vendorUpdatedItem);
            }` how do I get the items from the List ? I tried `vendorUpdatedItem.job = objectItems.job;` but it gives me an error

Comment: Error 2 'object' does not contain a definition for 'job' and no extension method 'job' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) \\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\vendorproject\vendorproject\models\connectionclass.cs 201 53 VendorProject

Comment: The method argument "vendorUpdateItems" should already contain the two objects that were passed from the javascript code. All  you have to do is use it in your method.